# MessageDlg with custom button captions in Delphi FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

With VCL you can use [`CreateMessageDialog` to generate a message dialog with custom button captions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5417843/2306907).

With FMX `CreateMessageDialog` does not seem to exist anymore (since XE3).

Is there a way to customize the button captions with FireMonkey other than rebuilding the message dialog from scratch?

What I would like to be able is to call a function as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5417959/2306907):

```
MessageDlg(
    'Really quit application ?', mtWarning,
    [ButtonInfo(mbNo, 'Do&n''t save'), 
     ButtonInfo(mbCancel, '&Cancel'),
     ButtonInfo(mbYes,'&Save')],
    mbYes
  );
```

Comment: I think that is a bad idea but you can edit in FMX.Consts and change those labels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no.  You don't have access to the actual dialog, like you do in VCL.  Like DadisX said in comment, you can only change the resource string values, but not touch the dialog itself.

However, with that said, FMX uses a platform abstraction layer to handle the actual dialog, and that you can tweak a bit.  On each supported platform, FMX has a class that implement's FMX's [`IFMXDialogService`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXDialogService) interface to provide platform-appropriate dialogs.  You can write your own class that implements `IFMXDialogService` and overrides its [`MessageDialog()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXDialogService.MessageDialog) method (amongst others) to do whatever you want with your own custom dialogs. Then you can unregister the default class for `IFMXDialogService` using [`TPlatformServices.RemovePlatformService()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Platform.TPlatformServices.RemovePlatformService) and register your class using [`TPlatformServices.AddPlatformService()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Platform.TPlatformServices.AddPlatformService).

Refer to Embarcadero's documentation for more details:

[FireMonkey Platform Services](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Services)

Answer (score 2):

I found [SynTaskDialog for Lazarus and FireMonkey](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/tree/master/SQLite3/Samples/ThirdPartyDemos/Ondrej/SynTaskDialog4Lazarus), a port of [SynTaskDialog](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/05/Open-Source-SynTaskDialog-unit-for-XP,Vista,Seven) to FireMonkey. SynTaskDialog uses the Windows TaskDialog API natively on newer Windows versions and emulates it on other platforms.

With this Open Source library I can define:

```
/// returns 100 if first button is pressed, 101 if second button is pressed, ...
function MessageDlgCustom(
  const MsgHeader: string; const MsgText: string; const DlgType: TMsgDlgType; 
  const Buttons: array of string; const DefaultButton: Integer = 0): TModalResult;
var
    Task: TTaskDialog;
    I: Integer;
    DlgIcon: TTaskDialogIcon;   
    Title: string;
begin
    case DlgType of
        TMsgDlgType.mtWarning:
            begin
                DlgIcon := tiWarning;
                Title := 'Warning';
            end;
        TMsgDlgType.mtError:
            begin
                DlgIcon := tiError;
                Title := 'Error';
            end;
        TMsgDlgType.mtInformation:
            begin
                DlgIcon := tiInformation;
                Title := 'Information';
            end;
        TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation:
            begin
                DlgIcon := tiQuestion;
                Title := 'Confirm';
            end;
        else begin
            DlgIcon := tiBlank;
            Title := '';
        end;
    end;
    Task.Title := Title;
    Task.Inst := MsgHeader;
    Task.Content := MsgText;
    for I := Low(Buttons) to High(Buttons) do
    begin
        if I <> Low(Buttons) then
          Task.Buttons := Task.Buttons + #13#10;
        Task.Buttons := Task.Buttons + Buttons[I];
    end;

    //see docu: custom buttons will be identified with an ID number starting at 100
    Result := Task.Execute([], DefaultButton, [], DlgIcon) - BUTTON_START;
end;
```

With this you can call:

```
case MessageDlgCustom('Quit application', 'Really quit application?', mtWarning,
  ['Save', 'Don''t save', 'Cancel']) of
    100: Quit(SAVE_YES);
    101: Quit(SAVE_NO);
    102: Abort;
end;
```

Comment: Seems to be untested on Android. From the [docs](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/tree/master/SQLite3/Samples/ThirdPartyDemos/Ondrej/SynTaskDialog4Lazarus): "FireMonkey support [...] for true cross-platform and cross-compiler use [...]. TaskDialog display would be native on Windows Vista+, emulated on all other platforms - Windows, Linux and OSX tested."