# Delphi firemonkey OSX how to use NSPanel?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Due to issues with TOpenDialog/TSaveDialog, I intent to use NSPanel, but I cant find a documentation or examples in Pascal/Delphi.
Does anybody has a code snipped about how to use NSOpenPanel and NSSavePanel with file filter (setallowedfiletype)?

Comment: I haven't noticed any problems, can you elaborate?

Comment: Here is my question about the issues I have with TOpenDialog and TSaveDialog. NSPanel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571019/delphi-firemonkey-mac-osx-popupmenu-issues-causing-form-to-reopen?noredirect=1#comment72317630_42571019 thats why I want to use NSOpenPanel and NSSavePanel if possible, but I cant find proper documentation for Delphi.

Comment: Here's how to use NSAlert, which should get you on your way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458701/firemonkey-equivalent-for-windows-messagebox